# Return user to initial application state on button press

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working on a navigation-based application, and in the last view I have a button that allows the user to go back to the first view -- in other words, restart the application.

How can I restart it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in a navigationBar based App, you could do:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But I'm not sure what you mean by "restart it".

Comment: i mean like you exit the app and run it again

Comment: Apple guidelines says that you should never quit an app programmatically, because it would look like a crash, in the other hand as soon as you're in springboard(IOS launcher) you have no control to launch the app again, the user has to enter manually, so what you could do is to go back to the first screen and have some logic that will clean all of the states and make the app look like a new launch.

Comment: do you know how can i disable the back buttom of the navigation bar in the last view

Comment: In the last view, in the viewDidLoadMethod: self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;